# Why does Dialyzer believe specs with too-specific return types?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I expect adding specs to never make things *less* safe, but that's exactly what happens in the following case.

In the following code, Dialyzer (wrongly) trusts me that the return type of bar is `1`. This leads it to saying that a pattern in foo() can never match–incorrect advice that, if heeded, would introduce a runtime error!

```erl
-module(sample).
-export([foo/0]).

foo() ->
    case bar() of
        1 -> ok;
        2 -> something
    end.

 -spec bar() -> 1.
bar() ->
  rand:uniform(2).
```

Deleting the spec for `bar/0` fixes the problem–but why did Dialyzer trust me?
Dialyzer is violating its "no false positives" promise here: it warns when there is no bug. And (even worse) Dialyzer nudges to introduce a new bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dialyzer calculates the success typing for each function before checking its spec, this action has several possible outcomes:

1. The spec type does not match the success type: Invalid type spec warning
2. The spec type is a strict supertype of the success type: Warning only with `-Wunderspecs` or `-Wspecdiffs`
3. The spec type is a strict subtype of the success type: Warning only with `-Woverspecs` or `-Wspecdiffs`.
4. The spec type and the success type match exactly: Everything's good
5. The spec type and the success type overlap but don't match exactly (like `-1..1` and `pos_integer()`): Same as 2.

For 1, it continues with the success type, otherwise continues with the intersection between the success type and the spec type.

Your case is 3, which is usually not warned about because you, as the programmer, know better (as far as dialyzer is concerned, maybe `rand:uniform(2)` can only return `1`). You can activate it with

```erlang
{dialyzer, [{warnings, [underspecs,overspecs]}]}.
```

in the `rebar.config` file

Comment: Thanks! Part of my question is *why* Dialyzer trusts me here. It's not just that it didn't warn - it's that it is actually incorporating the information from the spec. This doesn't seem to be what happens for underspecs, only for overspecs. Which is the opposite of what I'd expect: underspeccing is safe but overspeccing is not.

Comment: @MaxHeiber in both cases it incorporates the hints from the spec by using the type intersection as the type of the function, it just happens that the type intersection is the stricter type, which in 3 is the spec and in 2 is the success type. The key here is that it's perfectly possible for `rand:uniform(2)` to only be able to return `1` despite its spec saying `pos_integer()`, so 3 is a rather common case.

Answer (score 5):

Dialyzer's own analysis is (currently) based on over-approximations, of several kinds, so it cannot discern whether your stricter spec is due to you being definitely wrong or due to Dialyzer having over-approximated somewhere.

It therefore chooses to trust your spec, and goes for reporting a definitive error later based on that information.

In general, type-error-related info by other modern systems comes with "all parts reported and no blame explicitly assigned" for this reason. Here it is actually the case that the inference, the spec and the patterns being incompatible, but Dialyzer blames just the patterns. This is a quirk to have in mind when using it.